# How to show list Satellite on Android Sdk

Tags: android, sdk, satellite

I'm making an application about our satellites on Android. But I don't know how to get list Satellite.

Could you help me,please?

Comment: Have you tried to see tutorial about `ListView`

Comment: yep, I have. Could you help me,bro?

Comment: Well where did you get so far ? Whate specific issue are you facing ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a newbie in Android. and my English is not good. Could you tell me where and how to start to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know a little bit to Android but want to use `ListView` for the first time, you will find all useful information here http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

If you are really new to Android you can start with basic tutorial like this one https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html

Comment: Thank you, I have used ListView in android. But i didn't got your mean when you refer to ListView to this problem?

Comment: I understood that you want to display a list of satellite. That is why i think to list view.

Comment: oh yes, But i dont know how to get list of satellite?

Comment: Well i don't know how to answer that just like that... You can manually search google and make a `String[]` with the list. Or you have some database where there are store, or you can access it via a web service ?